# The Polynomial $P(x)=ax^4+4bx+c$ and some coefficient relationships

Tags: polynomials

If $P(x) = ax^4+4bx+c$ has real and non-zero coefficients, and a double root, then show that $ac^3 = 27b^4$

**SOLUTION** 
$$P(x) = ax^4 + 4bx+c$$
$$P'(x)=4ax^3+4b$$
So if $y$ is a double root then: 
$$ay^4+4by+c=0$$
$$4ay^4+4by=0 \Rightarrow ay^4=-by$$
So we get that $$3by+c=0\Rightarrow y=-\frac{c}{3b}$$
Now substitute into $P'(x)$ and the result immediately follows.

I was wondering if there are any other, perhaps, nicer solutions to this?

Comment: Maybe you mean $4ay^3+4b=0$...

Comment: @MattG88 I multiplied that equation that you wrote by $y$ so that I could substitute for $ay^4$. Apologies for skipping that step!

Comment: oh yes right!:-)

Comment: Where is your $a^2$ term coming from? and how did you get $b^4$ without a higher power of $c$ ?

Comment: fixed it, your conclusion works.

Answer (score 3):

don't know about nicer... the algebraic facts just use the formal derivative. if there is a double root, there is a nontrivial gcd of P and P' in the Euclidean ring of polynomials with real coefficients.

$$ q_1 = 4 P - x P' = 12 b x + 4 c  $$
$$  q_2 = a x^2 q_1 - 3 b P' = 4ac x^2 - 12 b^2 $$
$$ q_3 = acx q_1 - 3 b q_2 = 4 a^2 c x + 36 b^3  $$

Alright, the tea is ready..  We get a degree zero gcd, i.e. a constant, unless the two linear items we have seen are related by a constant multiplication, which would be
$$  a c^2 q_1 - 3 b q_3  $$
were a nonzero constant. So, 
$$  a c^2 q_1 - 3 b q_3 = 4 a c^3 - 108 b^4 = 4 (a c^3 - 27 b^4)  $$

LATER: this is  the actual Euclidean algorithm. It is annoying to use fractions, so I like to multiply through...
$$ r_1 = 4 P - x P' = 12 b x + 4 c  $$
$$ r_2 = 27 b^3 P' + (-9ab^2 x^2  + 3abc x - a c^2) r_1 = 108 b^4 - 4 a c^3  $$
Now, this $r_2$ really is a constant. If it is a nonzero constant, then $\gcd(P,P') = 1$ and there is no repeat factor, no double root of $P.$ Therefore the requirement is that $r_2 = 0,$ or
$$ 108 b^4 - 4 a c^3 = 0. $$

Comment: I fear I haven't studied Euclidean Rings! But unless you can find an error in my working -- there must be something wrong with this solution

Comment: @HughEntwistle fixed it. I originally put $a^2 c q_1$  and failed to notice it was not working. Meanwhile, before you get to any course with rings, suggest it is worth your time to learn how to find the gcd of two (one-variable) polynomials with easy coefficients.

Comment: @HughEntwistle the related skill I see lacking on this website is simple continued fractions, which is one way to write the method for finding the gcd of two positive integers. Again, not difficult, just need to be willing to go back and correct errors, as I had to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Another way yes but nicer I doubt a bit.

If $d$ is the double root we have $$ax^4+4bx+c=(x-d)^2(ax^2+ex+f)$$ It follows by equality of coefficients the system
$$-2ad+e=0\\ad^2-2ed+f=0\\ed^2-2df=4b\\d^2f=c$$ elimination of $e=2ad$ gives the system
$$ad^2-4ad^2+f=0\\2ad^3-2df=4b\\d^2f=c$$ finally elimination of $f$ gives
$$ad^3=b\\3ad^4=c$$ from which $$ac^3 = 27b^4$$